# React-Native: Unable to resolve 'react-navigation'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, react-navigation

Hi so I'm trying to create an android app within react-native within the app i'm trying to use react-navigation and i get the following error when i run the program with npx react-native run-android

```
error: Error: Unable to resolve module `@react-navigation/stack` from `src\nav\nav.js`: @react-navigation/stack could not be found within the project.

If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:
 1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
 2. Delete node_modules: rm -rf node_modules and run yarn install
 3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
 4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\Users\Ike\Desktop\Again\project\Project\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:186:15)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (C:\Users\Ike\Desktop\Again\project\Project\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\Users\Ike\Desktop\Again\project\Project\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:287:16)
    at Object.resolve (C:\Users\Ike\Desktop\Again\project\Project\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:267:42)
    at C:\Users\Ike\Desktop\Again\project\Project\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:434:31
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (C:\Users\Ike\Desktop\Again\project\Project\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:431:18)
    at C:\Users\Ike\Desktop\Again\project\Project\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:275:33
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (C:\Users\Ike\Desktop\Again\project\Project\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:87:24)
```

I've tried many things including using yarn instead of npm when trying to build the program. I've also tried deleted node_modules and removing react-navigation from packages.json and even npm install --save react-navigation

Comment: Please post your package.json. You need to install all required dependencies as mentioned in docs at https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

Do you also have all the dependencies installed?  react-native-gesture-handler, react-native-reanimated, react-native-screens and react-native-safe-area-context and @react-native-community/masked-view